# How to ensure maximum reaches certain value

Tags: calculus, optimization

Let us say we have a constant $C$ and variable $t$. There is a function, $p(t)$ whose second derivative is $C-t$. There is also a target maximum called $M$. For what value of $C$, would the maximum of $p(x)$, be $M$.

I tried taking the second integral of $C-t$, which I found to be:
$$\frac{t^2C}2-\frac{t^3}3$$
but that is where I got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have enough information about the function to answer the question. Given any $C$, there are many different function satisfying $p''(t)=C-t$, and they have various maxima. The biggest reason is that there are constants of integration that show up when you try to integrate to get $p$. So for instance, if $p(t)$ satisfies $p''(t) = C-t$, so does $p(t) + \alpha t + \beta$, for any $\alpha, \beta$, and these other terms will affect the maximum!

Further, if you mean the maximum on $\mathbb{R}$, many of these functions will not have maxima, even if they are continuous.

Comment: Okay, I figured out I was actually doing the problem wrong anyway, so there probably isn't a solution. (It was the first derivative, and the constant was $0$. Found C had to be $2\sqrt{5}$ if $M$ was $30$. Didn't do the general case. Again, different problem then what I typed.